# Select which column's data to return by using case or IF in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a T-SQL stored procedure which updates a table using a `merge` statement (I have simplified for brevity):

```
merge into Table_ACT as act
using (select s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, dbo.GetACTScheduleID(t.s1) as daily_schedule_id
       from dbo.RotaTmp t) as s on act.employeeid = s.employeeid

when matched then
    update set
    act.shiftcodeID = s.s1 .....qry continues after
```

It all works fine, but I have to repeat the query 7 times one for each day changing the line :

```
act.shiftcodeID = s.s1 to act.shiftcodeID = s.s2 then act.shiftcodeID = s.s3 etc
```

I would like to be able to select which 'S' field to use by using either an If or Case statement, but I just cannot figure out where to put it.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Could you post some sample data - for example part of the `target` table and part of the `source` table, and eventually the desired result.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
merge into Table_ACT as act
using (select s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, dbo.GetACTScheduleID(t.s1) as 
daily_schedule_id
   from dbo.RotaTmp t) as s on act.employeeid = s.employeeid

when matched then
update set
act.shiftcodeID = CASE WHEN <condition 1> THEN s.s1 
                       WHEN <condition 2> THEN s.s2
                       WHEN <condition 3> THEN s.s3
                       WHEN <condition 4> THEN s.s4
                       WHEN <condition 5> THEN s.s5
                       WHEN <condition 6> THEN s.s6
                       WHEN <condition 7> THEN s.s7
                       END
.....qry continues after
```